# how to change [null] to NULL in database?

Tags: database, image, laravel

[image]im storing multiple image in database as array.but if i didnt choose any image its storing [null] in database which is in array form as well. how i can change it to 'NULL'.
[image]

view blade:

```
   @foreach($reply['image'] as $imagePath)
       <img src="/image/{{ $imagePath }}" 
        style="width:150px; height:150px;"> 
   @endforeach
```

upload image :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >Image:</label>
    <form action="upload" id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" multiple><br />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why ? Because you can not handle the error of  undefined ?

Comment: in view  its displaying the unload image if its in [null] . thats why i wanted to change it to null . any other way to solve it

Comment: Just check if the array is empty where you're saving the record and insert `null` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check whether the array element is null or not.

```
@if(!$imagePath->isEmpty())
     <img src="/image/{{ $imagePath }}" 
        style="width:150px; height:150px;">

@else
```

Here if the image is not available you can add default image and use inside the `else if` statement.

You also can use is_null() instead of isEmply().

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use this in your migration:

```
$table->string('image')->default(NULL);
```

Then while checking from your view, just do

```
@if(!$imagePath)
No Image! (or default image path)
@else
(image display)
@endif
```